# Assigning an object property as the key of a new property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

What I am trying to do is take two properties of a single Javascript object, and creat a new array with the first property as a key for the second one.

```
var optionArray = {}

for (var i = 0; i < this.collection.models.length; i++) {

  var f = $('.optionChange:eq('+i+')')[0].value;

  if (f === "yes") { 
    this.collection.models[i].set({"optionValue":"yes"});
  }
  else{
    this.collection.models[i].set({"optionValue":"no"});
  }

  var option1 = this.collection.models[i].get("optionName");                  
  var option2 = this.collection.models[i].get("optionValue");
  var result = option1 + ":" + option2;

  optionArray[i] = {
    option1 : option2
  }

};
console.log(optionArray);
```

This however only outputs to {option1:"option2 property value"}. The key will not change, it only displays as the word option1. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just a side-note: `optionArray` is _not_ an array, but an object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong, since you can't use a variable as the property name when you use {} notation:

```
optionArray[i] = {
    option1 : option2
}
```

Try this instead:

```
optionArray[i] = {} // Make a new empty object
optionArray[i][option1] = option2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it like this:

```
optionArray[i] = {}
optionArray[i][option1] = option2;
```